# Firefox: when image NOT Found, it breaks html layer

Tags: jquery, html, css, image, firefox

In Firefox 27, when image not found, height of image becomes like auto to image alt.
This breaks html layer *(image 1)*. What can i do to make it similar to Chrome ( when image not found, height stay as previous) *(image 2)*

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify a static or minimum height through CSS, which will always keep its dimensions and layout will remain the same,

```
img {
min-height:300px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By my experience, `img` should have set attributes weight and height, just because of this situations. Those attributes help browser to create space for DOM element before it is rendered.
So, if your image is 100x100 px, then attributes should be `weight="100"`, `height="100"`. Notice that px is missing, since attributes are defined in pixels.

EDIT:
Just noticed. If you want to hide something when image is not loaded, then use jQuery plugin waitForImages. In case image is not loaded, hide its container.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? `$('img').wrap('<div/>').css({minHeight: '100px'});`

Answer (score 0):

set display inline block for the image:

```
img{display: inline-block;}
```